# Laravel display created_by and edited_by name using respective IDs

Tags: laravel

I have a table vehicle. This table has fields - created_by an edited_by. Every time a vehicle is created or edited, that particular user's ID is saved into this column.
In a show view where the details of this table is being displayed, I want to display the user's name not ID. What am I missing here or doing wrong?

**Vehicle model where I have related it to user:**

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer','customer_id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','edited_by');
    }
}
```

**Controller that displays the data:**

```
 public function show($id)
 {
    $vehicle = Vehicle::find($id);
    $files = File::where('vehicle_id',$id);
    return view('vehicles.show')->with('vehicle',$vehicle)
            ->with('files',$files);    
 }
```

**View**

```
<tr>
    <th>Created By</th>
    <td>{{$vehicle->user->name}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Last Edited By</th>
    <td>{{$vehicle->user->name}}</td>
</tr>
```

**User model where I put a hasmany relationship:**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function vehicles(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Vehicle');
    }  
}
```

Using a hasmany I am able to display either created_by or edited_by name. How could I display both created_by and edited_by names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your current relation on the Vehicle model matches the editor. In order to achieve the same for the creator you can create another relation to the User model and pass it the `created_by` column

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    public function customer(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer','customer_id');
    }

    public function creator(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','created_by');
    }

    public function editor(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','edited_by');
    }
}
```

And in your view, you can display the name using `$vehicle->creator->name` or `$vehicle->editor->name`

Answer (score 5):

Since you only have the `id` of the user, you have to fetch the name of the user from the database.
In your model you can add `Accessor` to achieve this.

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
     // rest of the code

    public function getCreatedByNameAttribute()
    {
        return User::where('id', $this->created_by)->pluck('name')->first();
    }
}
```

the you can access the `created by users name` as follows.

```
<tr>
    <th>Created By</th>
    <td>{{$vehicle->created_by_name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Do the same thing with `edited_by`

If you want to do this using relationships.

**NOTE : to do so, you have to have defined foreign keys on 'created_at'
 column to `user`**

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    // rest of the code

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'created_at', 'id');
    }
}
```

then you can access this as follows

```
<tr>
    <th>Created By</th>
    <td>{{$vehicle->creator->name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for the option. However, I am looking to make use of relationships (one to many / many to many) instead of directly fetching it from DB using query. Fetching name from DB can be done in my controller directly using -         $created_by = User::find($customer->created_by)->name;  and 
$edited_by = User::find($customer->edited_by)->name;